# Interesting ARG Image to be solved

Tags: visual, steganography

Someone in my college hosted an ARG game.
There is an image I've been trying to solve for a while.

**I have tried reading the EXIF, opening with Notepad, Changing various things in Photoshop [Saturation, HUE, exposure, etc].**

Nothing seemed to work.

I've noticed that the words **"Find out"** and **"Guess"** are slightly stronger green than the other letters.

[image]

Kind regards,

Beans.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried using the Hex Editor. No luck

Comment: maybe try to find the original image and use a diff tool? I found this one for example: https://userscontent2.emaze.com/images/400a82e1-5dc6-4f06-9deb-f3395193b8fc/30cc6fb975c2daf9d9a1e190bd2ef3e7.jpg but no clue if it is the original

Comment: Do you know anything about what *sort* of thing this is meant to lead you to? (The green text implies it's a message; is that right? What sort of message?)

Comment: [This](http://www.deviantart.com/art/Alice-White-Rabbit-156321173) seems like it may be the original original.

Comment: This image is supposed to lead me on to a link.
something like "/link.html"

Comment: Someone once sent me a .jpg file which was actually a .jpg and an archive (perhaps .zip or .7z) concatenated.  It would open as usual in an image viewer, but some Zip programs such as 7-zip would scan the stream for the archive header signature and then open it as an archive, that housed the actual payload.  But that doesn't seem to be the case for the image you've posted here.  Is this the original file, byte-for-byte?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder Absolutely not guaranteed. Imgur compresses things left and right. See the Maximum File Size section of [this page](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-).

Comment: Excuse the two-year late reply, I found this question while browsing the "unanswered" tab. I'm going to bet that you need a tool called **outguess** to get the solution.

Comment: could you please upload the original image to google drive or dropbox and attach a link?

Comment: imgur compresses images too much

Answer (score 1):

Remember Cicadia3301?

> I think you have to use the program "Outguess" on that image, that's what the highlighted words mean. C3301 had a very similar puzzle to that one.

Helpful link:

> https://uncovering-cicada.fandom.com/wiki/OutGuess

You're welcome!

Comment: The result of trying the suggestion here is what seems to be in SysEx (or .syx) format. I don't have any software capable of working with it, but perhaps someone with experience working with MIDI files can determine for sure if the output is a meaningful SysEx file.

Comment: Nice!, so I was pretty much correct! I tried running the image trough outguess before but I had a hard time getting it to work so I kinda gave up on that. Thanks for the help and good luck with that ARG!